# RecyclerView click when item is changed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my RecyclerView there is a filter data in searchview. Clicking on an item is implemented in ViewHolder
Now I want OnItemClickListener through the interface, and everything works until the order of items is sorted out when sorting, for example, when searching for the 20th position, it becomes the first and is treated as the first. 5 the position becomes 1 place but is processed as 1. How to properly bind the ID in this case?

snachala bylo tak

at first it was so:

```
ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView name;

    StationViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(context, DetailStation.class);
        i.putExtra("pos1",listStations.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());

        context.startActivity(i);
```

and caught an event:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            position = bundle.getString("pos1");
}

        bus3_txt_2.setText(position2);
```

how to do now?

Comment: please post your adapter code, and the code where you implement search

Answer (score 0):

I do this: searchView. the fragment itself. If it does not work, then I output the text of the view with the inscription - data NOT found

this is my fragment

```
// is my fragment
public class MyFragment
        extends Fragment
        implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
//
//фрагепмнт


 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
        return false;
    }

    private List<ItemListStation>
    filter(List<ItemListStation> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<ItemListStation> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ItemListStation model : models)     {
            final String text;
            text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        final List<ItemListStation> filteredModelList = filter(listStationItemList, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        textViewSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (filteredModelList.isEmpty()) {
            View myView = textViewSearch;
            slideToBottom(myView);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void slideToBottom(View view){
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shake);
        if (view.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.startAnimation(shake);
        }
    }
```

this is my adapter

```
 class Bus2Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Bus2Adapter.StationViewHolder> {

private List<ItemBusStation> listStations;

Bus2Adapter(List<ItemBusStation> listStations) {
    this.listStations = listStations;    }

@Override
public StationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.item_bus_station, parent, false);
    return new StationViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(listStations.get(position).getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listStations.size();
}

class StationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView name;

    StationViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(context, DetailStation.class);
        i.putExtra("pos1", listStations.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}

public void setFilter(List<ItemBusStation> listStationLists)    {
    listStations = new ArrayList<>();
    listStations.addAll(listStationLists);
    notifyDataSetChanged();    }
```

}

this is my item

```
ItemBusStation implements Serializable {
private String name;

public ItemBusStation(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```